# Should I use make or makes?

Tags: grammar

I was talking to friend about breeding animals and I told her "it doesn't makes me mad anymore." Later I read out msgs and "makes" looks just weird.

So should it be..?

> It doesn't **make** me mad anymore

or

> It doesn't **makes** me mad anymore

Comment: Please avoid text abbreviations such as **msgs**, not every user is familiar with its meaning, and it's not as though you lack space or time to write **messages** in full. BTW and IINM,  I believe  "texts" is used more common in relation to smart phones.

Comment: You may not be aware of the purpose of this site. It will become clear if you finish reading the Tour. You may also not be aware that there is a site called English Language Learners, which I think is where questions of this type should be posted.

Comment: @David tip - if you put `[tour]` it does a link too - [tour]. and `[ell.se]` does [ell.se]

Comment: @marcellothearcane — Just joined this site to thank you. I never knew that. (Like many things on SE, unfortunately) Very useful when I'm on the phone and can't find the URL.

Answer (score -1):

You should use "make" when the subject is plural, "makes" when singular:

- It makes me mad
- They make me mad.

"Makes" is the *third-person singular simple present* tense of "make", so if a singular thing *makes* you mad, it repeatedly does so, or does so on an ongoing basis. If something only maddened you once you would say "it *made* me mad".

The same applies to the similar verb *madden*:

- It maddens me
- They madden me

Answer (score -1):

This question is about subject-verb agreement. Your instinct is right: it should be "make". This is because it follows "doesn't", which is an auxiliary. In terms of agreeing with the subject, the first auxiliary takes precedence over the main verb:

- SINGULAR: It **doesn't** make me mad.
- PLURAL: Those things **don't** make me mad.

Another example, with multiple auxiliaries:

- SINGULAR: The dog **has** been playing.
- PLURAL: The dogs **have** been playing.

Comment: Nope: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Do+not+makes+this+mistake%2CDo+not+make+this+mistake&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3